# Powershell variable in replacement string with named groups

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

The following Powershell replace operation with named groups s1 and s2 in regex (just for illustration, not a correct syntax) works fine :

```
$s -Replace "(?<s1>....)(?<s2>...)" '${s2}xxx${s1}'
```

My question is : how to replace with a variable $x instead of the literal xxx, that is, something like :

```
$s -Replace "(?<s1>....)(?<s2>...) '${s2}$x${s1}'
```

That doesn't work as Powershell doesn't replace variable in single quoted string but the named group resolution doesn't work anymore if replacement string is put in double quotes like this "${s2}$x${s1}".

Comment: ``"`${s2}$x`${s1}"``

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly ! It really makes sense when you have the answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@PetSerAl comment is correct, here is code to test it:

```powershell
$sep = ","
"AAA BBB" -Replace '(?<A>\w+)\s+(?<B>\w+)',"`${A}$sep`${B}"
```

**Output**:
`AAA,BBB`

**Explanation**:

Powershell will evaluate the double quoted string, escaping the $ sign with a back tick will ensure these are not evaluated and a valid string is provided for the -Replace operator.

- [msdn about replace operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh847759.aspx)
- [msdn about escape characters](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847755.aspx)

or via `Get-Help about_escape` & `Get-Help about_comparison_operators`

Comment: You are the reason i still have hair on my head man. Thank you for this!