# Why does my Powershell script to convert .vss to .vssx result in errors on execution?

Tags: powershell, type-conversion, visio

Does this seem to be correct? I am getting errors on trying to convert `.vss` to `.vssx`.

```
     >> $directoryToUpdate='C:\office\Stencils\*'
     >> $visio= New-Object -comVisio.Application
     >> foreach($vssFile in (get-childitem "$directoryToUpdate\*.vss" -Recurse")){
     >>    write-host "Working on $vssfile"
     >>    $doc=$visio.Documents.Open($vssFile.FullName)
     >>    $vssxFileName=[io.path]::ChangeExtension($vssFile,'.vssx')
     >>    $doc.SaveAs($VSSXFileName)
     >>    $doc.close();
     >> }
```

The output error messages are:

```
At line:1 char:21
+ >> foreach($vssFile in (get-childitem "$directoryToUpdate\*.vss" -Rec ...
+                     ~~
Unexpected token 'in' in expression or statement.
At line:1 char:20
+ >> foreach($vssFile in (get-childitem "$directoryToUpdate\*.vss" -Rec ...
+                    ~
Missing closing ')' in expression.
At line:19 char:73
+ ... ch($vssFile in (get-childitem "$directoryToUpdate\*.vss" -Recurse")){
+                                                                        ~
Unexpected token ')' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: Please help us make clear what you want to ask. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You can help PowerShell to find the end of a variable name is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30543753/powershell-variable-in-replacement-string-with-named-groups

Comment: Remove the double-quote after `-Recurse` on line 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say you are overcomplicating this. Here is a slight refactor of your code.

```
$visio = New-Object -com Visio.Application

 Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\office\Stencils\*.vss' -Recurse | 
 ForEach-Object {
    "Working on $($PSItem.Name)"

    $doc          = $visio.Documents.Open($PSItem.FullName)
    $vssxFileName = [io.path]::ChangeExtension($PSItem,'.vssx')

    $doc.SaveAs($VSSXFileName)
    $doc.close()
 }
```